# nginx passenger The website under heavy load error and no queue is processed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

i am getting this error message. i understand this is because of queues but it always stays like this (no queue is  processed. it is stuck). using passenger 4 and nginx. i had to restart nginx to get it working

This website is under heavy load

We're sorry, too many people are accessing this website at the same time. We're working on this problem. Please try again later.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The website is under heavy load + ROR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537185/the-website-is-under-heavy-load-ror)