# This website is under heavy load, rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am getting error, I tried searching a lot. And seen many posts but nothing worked for me. Any suggestions on how to fix this.

> This website is under heavy load
>
> We're sorry, too many people are accessing this website at the same time. We're working on this problem. Please try again later.

when I run `free -m`, this is the memory status

[image]

and seeing nginx configuration file, these are my settings

[image]

I tried modifying settings, according to different things specified by people on stackoverflow. But I still facing the issue

Answer (score 2):

The Passenger documentation and the following article explain what this error is, why you get it, and how you can make it go away:

- https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_max_request_queue_size
- [What is optimal value for Phusion passenger PassengerMaxRequestQueueSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402801/what-is-optimal-value-for-phusion-passenger-passengermaxrequestqueuesize)

Comment: thanks for the reply, I seen one of them. Let me check other one.