# This website is under heavy load (queue full)

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger

I am having problems with my site in aws, it shows me the following message: "This website is under heavy load (queue full)" I was reading and apparently it is because multiple users access at the same time, I tried to modify the value of the queue but I did not find which was the file, in the end I modified the file located in `/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/nginx/config_options.rb` but I'm not sure if it was there that I should modify it. Modified from this:

```
  { 
    :name     => 'passenger_max_request_queue_size',
    :scope    => :application,
    :type     => :uinteger,
    :default  => DEFAULT_MAX_REQUEST_QUEUE_SIZE
  },
```

to this:

```
  { 
    :name     => 'passenger_max_request_queue_size',
    :scope    => :application,
    :type     => :uinteger,
    :default  => 2000
  },
```

I restarted nginx with `sudo service nginx restart` but I try to access the site and it is loading for a long time and fails to show the content. my application is developed with rails 5 is hosted on aws (my plan is the basic one), with passenger and nginx

My application was already working correctly but today it presented that problem.

Comment: Did you see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31670217/this-website-is-under-heavy-load-rails-app