# Custom Phusion Passenger error page queue full

Tags: nginx, passenger

My site is currently down due to hardware errors on the physical host. Phusion Passenger is returning this unsightly error, even though we have a nice custom 500 error page configured in nginx. Is it possible to change?

[image: This website is under heavy load (queue full)]

I have configured passenger with the following:

```
passenger_friendly_error_pages off;
passenger_intercept_errors on;
```

And customized the error page in `/opt/nginx/html/50x.html`. And restarted. Yet nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you figure it out? Am facing the same issue.

Comment: @AnidhyaAhuja nope. This is still an issue I'm facing.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23369562/1418337) wil get you going in the right direction.